# Updating custom WTForm widged from SQLAlchemy object

Tags: python, forms, sqlalchemy, wtforms

`Boolean` widget is a checkbox in WTForms, while I want to have a yes/no dropdown rather than "true/false" selection in generated form.

This custom widget almost works:

```
class SelectYesNo(SelectField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['choices'] = [('Yes', 'Yes'), ('No', 'No')]
        super(SelectYesNo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            try:
                self.data = False
                if valuelist[0] == 'Yes':
                    self.data = True
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError(u'Invalid Choice: could not coerce (valuelist: {0})'.format(valuelist))

    def pre_validate(self, form):
        pass
```

Now, it *works* when I'm using `.populate_obj` method on a form, that is, it stores `bool` in SQLAlchemy object correctly, like `form.populate_obj(SQAItem())` (I can see in the DB that correct value has been stored in the table).

Where it does *not* work is reading SQA object value into this widget in the form, like `form = form_class(request.POST, sqa_item_instance)`, where `sqa_item_instance` has been read from SQLAlchemy and has a bool field.

How can I get that, that is, "populate" form `SelectYesNo` field correctly from SQA item?